# Why does CakePHP put app/Config in .gitignore by default?

Tags: git, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.1

Why does CakePHP put app/Config in .gitignore by default?

I understand putting app/tmp in .gitignore, and also understand why they've put the root /plugins and /vendors directorys, since they are intended for plugins and vendors that are shared across multiple projects. But why app/Config? I would have thought that contains exactly the kind of stuff you DO want in version control, such as database.php and bootstrap.php.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd imagine it would have something to do with the database configs are actually what you **DONT** want in version control.

Imagine If you have the database config file in your git repo, and someone pulls, they will have YOUR database settings, then they will edit the database config file to suit their needs, and now it just becomes a game of table tennis with database.php files. And quite frankly that would be very very, annoying.

I mean, if everyone has the same config settings, it would work and might be a tad handy, but who has all the database configs across machines?

bootstrap.php on the other hand i'll somewhat agree with, since the bootstrapping is usually for a project and the project relies on those dependencies. Although that being said, what if you want to use different  plugins for different environments? Such as using sendgrid.com to send emails on your development copy, and using SMTP on the live server?

In my opinion its just simpler to leave the config directory ignored. It leaves the configuration to the developer.

Comment: I always set it up so that database.php does a switch and uses a different config depending on the URL that the site is being accessed by - so multiple developers (and live/local versions of a site) sharing the same database.php is not a problem. I'd imagine doing it any other way would be a nightmare, regardless of whether or not the database.php file is in version control. Likewise with bootstrap, I'd imagine that not having all environments handled in the one bootstrap file would be a nightmare, right?

Comment: I mean I guess you could argue that for a some people, Config is best left out of git, but to leave it out by DEFAULT?? You'd think there must be a really good reason.

Comment: I personally would rather not having a larger switch statement to config databases, because for every user / server you have to add a new one, and that could be a bit messy. I don't think there's a REALLY good reason, it's just they'd rather not have the one database file across a lot of people.

Comment: @joshua.paling that idea is nice, till you try and use the shell where there is no url.

Comment: @dogmatic69 Hmm yeah, I guess. So I take it when people add some extra code to Bootstrap, then then manually copy it round to other places and let each developer on the team know? Sounds annoying. A bit disappointing that there's not a better solution, but that's life!

Comment: The only file I dont include is `database.php`. The rest can be made as abstract as you like. eg: [this](https://github.com/infinitas/infinitas) works out the box for pretty much any setup

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer is correct in that you don't want your database config in the repository, but slightly misses an important point.

You do not want to include your database config in a repository; if someone gains access to the this they will have access to sensitive details like your database's login/password and therefore gain direct access to it!

In CakePHP 3.x only the `app.php` config file is ignored by default which contains the database setup. There is an `app.default.php` file included which should be used as a template for people to setup an app on their local machine or the server without the need for storing sensitive data in the repository.

If you're deploying an app with something like [Capistrano](http://capistranorb.com/) or [Rocketeer](http://rocketeer.autopergamene.eu/) then a good practice is to keep the file containing the database configuration in a shared directory and symbolically link to this when deploying. That way, apart from initial setup, you do not need to worry about losing the config when deploying from a repository.

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently working in CakePHP v.3.1.

From the CakePHP documentation, it doesn't say to exclude app.php from the version control, but only to exclude file app_local.php.

https://book.cakephp.org/3/en/development/configuration.html

> The application skeleton features a config/app.php file which should
> contain configuration that doesn’t vary across the various
> environments your application is deployed in. The config/app_local.php
> file should contain the configuration data that varies between
> environments and shouldn’t be checked into version control.

For my case, since I use .env files, and I don't want to have multiple config files to setup in each environment, I included app.php under version control, but used env to get sensitive parameters from the .env file, like so:

```
'username' => env('DB_LOGIN'),
'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD'),
'database' => env('DB_DATABASE'),
```